# Facebook Login Error in my Android Game (are there different key hash from ones shown)?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, android-unity-plugin

Right now I seem to have a problem with the Facebook Unity SDK 7.7 and Unity 5.3.4f
I have already copied the debug key hash from Unity and paste it into my app settings in the Facebook Developers Page. I've also correctly named my projects etc and made it live.

Everything is working well in my Game. I am able to log into Facebook from my game and Invite Friends.

Problem is whenever I uninstall my game, and reinstall, or "build and run with signed keystore" I am unable to login to Facebook again. It gives me an error of "Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later".

Now if I go to my app settings in Facebook and look under "Logged in with Facebook" my game app is there. So I remove it and then I am able to log back in again. But if the user gets an update or logs out from Facebook in the game, same login error pops up.
Any help would be great!

Comment: I believe that this error is because you aren't calling the needed method on Awake(). The first example gives you all you need -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that there are 2 different hash keys. Ones for release and the other one is for debug which is the default key hash shown in the "Unity Facebook Settings". Now to get the release hash key, that was a mission!

So if you build your APK file and sign it with your keystore, each of those keystores produce a different key hash which is used in your Facebook App Settings.
But if you build and run without signing, its the default debug hash key.